# How to manipulate char - C

Tags: c

In my program, I need the user to enter coordinates, starting with a letter and finishing by a number. The format is "e6", for example. I want to write a function that converts the number into an int. With this example, i want the "6" to be converted to int 6. My problem comes from the fact that the number can go up to 11.

I tried this function :

```
int function(char c[]) {

    if (c[2]=='0') {
        return (int)c[1] * 10;
    }

    else if (c[2]=='1') {
        return (int)c[1]*10 + 1;
    }

    else {
        return (int)(c[1]-'0');
    }
}
```

The problem is that it returns numbers unrelated to the input, like "490" if I enter "f10".

I hope my problem is clear enough so you can help me !

**Answer :** I understand now my error, and what -'0' means. The new working function is :

```
int function(char c[]) {

    if (c[2]=='0') {
        return (int)(c[1]-'0') * 10;
    }

    else if (c[2]=='1') {
        return (int)(c[1]-'0')*10 + 1;
    }

    else {
        return (int)(c[1]-'0');
    }
}
```

Thanks to all of you !

Comment: "I want to write a function that converts the number into an int" i dont understand this phrase

Comment: Is `"e6"` a string and to which which number it shall convert?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio the way I read it is that the input consists of a letter and a number, as "<letter><number>". The letter is irrelevant, the number needs to be parsed to an integer. The trouble is that it's not a single character, as it can run up to `11` - and that's where OP's stuck.

Comment: @N.Wouda you're right, that's what I wanted to say

Comment: @LoneRetriever But why the pointer to `char`? Do you store both in an array of `char`?

Comment: This example is still omitting some part to reproduce the problem. How do you call the function? With which argument?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio if I understand well what you're asking, the input is stored as char c[] = {'f', '1', '0'}

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio like this : printf("%d", function("f10");

Comment: Wouldn't storing a coordinate in a struct make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Here you convert a digit character to its value by subtracting `'0'`:

```
return (int)(c[1]-'0');
```

That's correct (although the cast is completely unnecessary).

But here you just use the digit character as though it were a value:

```
return (int)c[1] * 10;
```

Since `'1'` is 49, the output is not surprising.

Comment: Maybe you shall mention explicitly, that the OP is using the wrong index number, which you have corrected.